# Nested ordered list in ascendent order

Tags: css, html-lists

I try to show an ordered list from 1 to 7.

```
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2
  <ol>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Expected:

[image]

Comment: So, what have you tried? This is quite easy to achieve using CSS counters, you just need to specify the place where the counter resets properly.

Comment: Do you want to make a list like?
1)
2) 
 2.1) 
2.2)
3)

Comment: @Rajibkarmaker no, i need 1 2 3 4 5 6.

Comment: @CBroe can you explain how to make the counter go from 1 to 7, not to reset at every nested ol ?

Comment: Please read here then try yourself again https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734084/how-to-achieve-the-following-automatic-numbering-using-css-or-js/51734144#51734144

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Rajibkarmaker, was about counter-reset the first ol and then counter-increment to every li!

`ol.example{counter-reset: section;}
ol.example,ol.example ol {list-style:none}
ol.example li::before {counter-increment: section; content: counter(section);}`